# How to call a javascript from C++ in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am developing an app that displays a map. When continuously sending data from C++ to JavaScript (with QML as an intermediary), it takes a long time for the map to be displayed or does not display.

I suspect that this is due to the intermediary QML layer.

I am looking for a way to call a JavaScript function from C++ without going through QML. Is this feasible?

main.cpp:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    set_qt_environment();

    QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("NaviMap");
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts);
    QtWebEngineQuick::initialize();

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    foo *foo_object = new foo();
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("obj_server", foo_object->data);


    const QUrl url(u"qrc:Main/main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(
                &engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated, &app,
                [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    },
    Qt::QueuedConnection);

    engine.addImportPath(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/qml");
    engine.addImportPath(":/");

    engine.load(url);

    QTimer timer;
    timer.setInterval(1000/60);
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, foo_object, &foo::updatePosition);
    timer.start();

    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty()) {
        return -1;
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

App.qml:

```js
QtObject{
        id: backendId
        WebChannel.id: "backend"
    }

    WebChannel {
        id: myWebChannel
        registeredObjects: backendId
    }

    WebEngineView {
        id: webview
        anchors.fill: parent
        webChannel: myWebChannel
        settings.javascriptEnabled: true
        url: "html/index.html"
        profile {
            httpCacheType: WebEngineProfile.DiskHttpCache
            persistentCookiesPolicy: WebEngineProfile.ForcePersistentCookies
        }
        settings {
            autoLoadImages: true
            dnsPrefetchEnabled: false
        }
        onLoadingChanged:
        {
            if (webview.loadProgress === 100)
            {
                isLoad = true;
            }
        }
    }
Connections {
        target: obj_server

        function onMap_naviChanged() {
            var lat0 = obj_server.map_navi.lat_raw;
            var lon0 = obj_server.map_navi.lon_raw;
            var lat1 = obj_server.map_navi.lat_est;
            var lon1 = obj_server.map_navi.lon_est;
            var heading = obj_server.map_navi.direction;

            if(false)
            {

                webview.runJavaScript(`recvGps(${lat0},${lon0},${lat1},${lon1},${heading});`);
            }
        }
    }
```

myJS.js

```js
function initMap() {
    var webChannel = new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel){
        backend = channel.objects.backend;
....
    });
function recvGps(lat0, lon0, lat1, lon1, direction) {
    var rawPos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat0, lon0);
    var estPos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lon1);

    raw.setPosition(rawPos);
    est.setOptions({
                             position: estPos,
                             icon: { ...icon, rotation: direction }
                         });

}
```

**[Update]**

Here, I use HTML to display the map and import it into QML. If I follow this approach, QML won't display the map. However, if I reduce the frame rate from 60FPS to 30FPS, it displays normally. Does anyone have a solution for running at 60FPS or a more optimized way to send data?

[image]

Comment: There are multiple approaches. The "normal" way to do this is to create a QObject with a signal and to emit your signal as often as you need. Then, on the QML side just attach a Javascript function to the signal and your Javascript will be raised whenever the signal is emitted from C++. If you wish Javascript to respond, the signal can pass as an argument a mechanism where you can respond to the signal from the Javascript.

Comment: @StephenQuan I would like to ask a bit more because I'm new to developing with QT. With the provided sample, the map doesn't seem to load. Do you know the reason? Is it possible that there's too much data sent from the C++ side, causing the map not to function properly on the QML side?

Answer (score -1):

You need to register an instance of your class like as a Singleton with a version, and inside the C++ class, you can create new signal.

```cpp
qmlRegisterSingletonType<T>(MainQmlUri, 1, 0, name, makeSharedSingleton<T, function>);
```

```cpp
public signals:
void callJsFunction();
```

Then you need to call this function on your function:

```cpp
void someFunction() {
   doThis();
   emit callJsFunction();
}
```

In QML side, we need to handle this signal. For this, we need to create a connection with our `SharedSingletonType`.

```js
import MainQmlUri 1.0
import yourJs as logic.

Connection {
  onCallJsFuntion(){
  logic.initMap();
  }
  target: YourC++ClassName(how you register)
}
```

That's all.

Comment: I try but error: Invalid import qualifier ID at line import yourJs as logic.